# How to create link triggering submit event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following piece of code:

```
<form name="ProjectButtonBar_deleteProject_LF_3" action="" method="post">
<a class="buttontext" href="javascript:document.ProjectButtonBar_deleteProject_LF_3.submit()">...</a>
```

As you can see, clicking the link causes "hard" submit of the form. Instead of this, I would like to trigger submit event. It is so, because in another file there is a code executed in reaction to submit event. With the code shown in this example, this code is being ignored. I can't change the href attribute by hand, beause whole "a" tag is generated by framework.
How should I do this using jQuery? I suppose I have to modify href somehow, but how? Or maybe there is another solution?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle explaining your situation?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of triggering the click event on the submit button, use jQuery to trigger the submit action on the form.

```
$('form').trigger('submit');
```

This will trigger any event that's been attached to the form via `.on('submit')`

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can do it easily:

```
<form name="ProjectButtonBar_deleteProject_LF_3" id="form1" action="" method="post">

<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit"/>

</form>

<a class="buttontext">...</a>



$('.buttontext').on('click',function(e){

e.preventDefault();

$('input#btnSubmit').click();

});
```

or submit form programmatically:

```
$('.buttontext').on('click',function(e){

   e.preventDefault(); 

   $('form#form1').submit();

    });
```

Comment: Ok. But does handling click event on 'a' element prevent from executing the JavaScript code present in href attribute?

Comment: what you mean by that, means its href url will not hit?

Comment: I mean that what happens when click event handling is done? Isn't JavaScript present in the href attribute executed, what leads to second submit() execution?

Comment: when we write javascript event, whenever the element is clickd that method is called, after this method execution if href has some url page will be redirected to it

Comment: So it is not the solution I want. I would like to trigger submit event and ignore what is in href then. I would like to overwrite default behavior generated by framework.

Comment: you can return false at the end of event to stop it

Comment: i prefer to use preventDefault see the edited answer